# Relativistic equation for the Doppler effect

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

From Robert Resnick's "Introduction to Special Relativity", the frequencies in two different inertial frames as shown below,

[image]

are related by
$$f = f'\frac{1+\beta \cos\theta'}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
which can be written inversely as
$$f' = f\frac{1-\beta \cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
He says that in the second equation, *f* is the observed frequency, and *f '* is the proper frequency. Shouldn't *f '* be the observed frequency and *f* be  the proper frequency in the second equation? Since, from my understanding, in the inverse situation, the source is in *S* and *f '* is the frequency in *S'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of equations is entirely symmetric. Whether $f$ or $f'$ is larger will depend entirely on the sign of $\beta$.

To achieve the inverse transformation is simply a case of swapping the labels between the primed and unprimed quantities and changing the sign of $\beta$, such that $\beta \rightarrow -\beta$ and $\beta^2 \rightarrow (-\beta)^2$.

The "inverse situation" is not that the source is in frame $S$, it is simply to write the frequency observed in the primed frame in terms of quantities in the unprimed frame. Frame $S'$ travels at velocity ${\bf v}$ with respect to $S$, so frame $S$ travels at velocity ${\bf -v}$ with respect to $S'$.

Putting the source in frame $S$ would just swap the primed and unprimed labels but leave the sign of $\beta$ unchanged.

The diagram is confusing though. As drawn, it appears to show a light ray in a direction that is travelling generally away from the origin of frame $S$. However, the observer in frame $S$ cannot be at the origin of $S$ if they are to receive the radiation emitted in $S'$.

Comment: Thank you so much on the clarification of the inverse situation. I could derive the second equation from the first equation using the relation between $\theta$ and $\theta '$. In the case of the source in $S$, isn't the sign of $\beta$ changed since the source (which is now $S$) is moving relative to the observer (which is now $S '$) in a direction opposite that of the original case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "proper" frequency, as "proper" refers to a rest frame, and light has no rest frame. There's just a frequency in a frame, and of course (un)primed $f$ refers to (un)primed $S$.

It's natural to say the emitting frame is the proper frame; however, this is really a Galilean way to look at. For instance, imagine it's a spectral line in a star: the star is the emitting frame. Or is it? What, then, is Doppler broadening? The emitting atom is moving, and doesn't share the star's inertial frame.

Finally: the diagram is a bit off. It's somewhat traditional to start in the unprimed frame, and then transform to the primed frame. You don't have to do it this way, but it increases confusion (see for example: [Relativistic equation for the Doppler effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/756096/relativistic-equation-for-the-doppler-effect)). Moreover, the ray as drawn is moving away from $O$ and thus won't be observed in $S$, unless the observer is not at the origin...which just adds another point of confusion.

Note also that the relativistic Doppler equations are symmetric, unlike the original sound-wave version. In the sound case, there is an absolute rest frame: the medium (air), so the equations for emitter and receiver are different. This simply cannot be the case in special relativity.